# copy file to all subfolders and all subsubfolders

Tags: linux

Copy a file into all subfolders and subsubfolders.

I have a file say, a.txt

I want to copy it to all subfolders and all the folders within those folders. I have tried creating a script to run this, but I keeping getting errors.

Any help?

the code i was trying was below. But this only copies it into subdirectories, not subsubdirectories

```
for i in ./* # iterate over all files in current dir
do
    if [ -d "$i" ] # if it's a directory
    then
        cp a.txt "$i" # copy a.txt into it
    fi
done
        cd ..
    done
```

Comment: To better help some more information is needed. What OS are you running the script on? can you post the script you have and what error you are gettings?

Comment: linux. i edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script only copies into subdirectories because that's all you are telling it to do (`./*` is all files in current directory, and you never go any deeper). You could implement it recursively, but it's probably easier to just do something like:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -exec cp a.txt {} \;
```

Or, [for POSIX compliance and maximum portability](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17389439/616460):

```
find . ! -path . -type d -exec cp a.txt {} \;
```

That will do what you want: copy *a.txt* to every (sub)+directory in the current tree.

You can use the `-maxdepth` option to limit the depth of subdirectories if you want. You can use the `-mindepth` option (where available) to set a minimum depth limit. In the first example above we use `-mindepth 1` to skip `.` to avoid outputting a warning about copying a file onto itself -- it's not absolutely necessary but it's nice to not have warnings.

For more information about `find` check out its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

Comment: When I Do that I get:
cp: `a.txt' and `./a.txt' are the same file

Comment: @user440178 Yes, you would get that from the `.` returned by `find`. It is an easy problem to diagnose, if you spend a second playing with `find` you can readily see that it outputs `.`. The operation still succeeds just fine. If the warning bothers you, [use the info here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525004/how-to-exclude-this-current-dot-folder-from-find-type-d) to construct a solution without the warning.

Comment: Is there a way to make it only go in subsubfolders and not subfolders?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's working, it just is hanging for a while

Comment: @user440178 *"Is there a way to make it only go in subsubfolders and not subfolders?"* When you read the post I linked to and saw the `-mindepth` option, did you discover your own answer to this question?

Comment: @user440178 *"I'm not sure that it's working, it just is hanging for a while"* The command works. If it's hanging for you then something else is going on and you'll need to provide more info. I would expect it to take some time if the source file is large and/or you have a lot of subdirectories. You could always do a little bit of debugging to determine where it is hanging, for example `cp` has a `-v` option.

Comment: so should min depth 2 be right then?

Comment: @user440178 When you type `find . -mindepth 2 -type d` by itself, does it list the directories you want? If so then yes it should be 2. If not then use a different depth.